# What's the difference between “d'avoir” and “avoir”?

Tags: prépositions

Here are two example sentences :

> Je suis heureux d'avoir fait votre connaissance.
>
> Il est triste avoir perdu son emploi.

Both constructions with "avoir" are used under the same circumstance which is after an adjective of feeling.
Can someone explain to me the difference between "d'avoir" and "avoir"?  Is it the same when "être" is used instead of "avoir"?

Comment: The second sentence is wrong, it should be "*Il est triste **d'avoir** perdu son emploi*".

Answer (score 6):

There is an error in the second sentence: it must be "d'avoir" also and not "avoir". This construction with verbs in the infinitive is not specific to adjectives of feelings but to many adjectives, although not all; the verb used is not a problem: "être" is also used; the conjunction "que" is used with finite forms.

**de**

- impossible de comprendre, de se rappeler, de payer ces prix exorbitants,…
- heureux de savoir sa conjugaison, de partir en vacance, d'être ici, …
- intéressant de connaitre, de voyager sans contraintes,…
- recommandable de veiller à ses affaires sur cette plage, …
- difficile de voir (dans ce brouillard), de croire, …
- faisable de manger du rôti avec les doigts,…
- facile d'être dans les premiers, d'être dans cette équipe,…
- <s>critique de</s> réussir dans ce domaine,…

**que**

- impossible que la température soit à moins trente à l'équateur,…
- heureux que vous soyez ici, que le temps des vacances soit enfin arrivé, …
- évident que l'eau soit salée puisqu'elle vient de la mer, que le froid tue,…